# How to Fix error in javaFx error Message?

Tags: css, javafx

I'am using CSS file with JavaFX (scene builder),I ran into a problem that I couldn't find a solution for.
I searched a lot and couldn't find a solution to this problem

```
   .linear-grad {

-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom left,#5f0a87,#a4508b);
}

.button1 {
    -fx-background-color :#5F0E81;
    -fx-text-fill:#ffffff;
}
.button1:hover{ 
  -fx-text-fill:#6E1988;
}
.button1 :pressed {
     -fx-text-fill:#CEB2D7;
    
}
.button1 :active {
      -fx-text-fill:#B184BF;
}

.button2 {
    -fx-background-color :#863684;
    -fx-text-fill : #ffffff;
}

.button2:hover{ 
  -fx-text-fill:#994984;
}
.button2:pressed {
      -fx-text-fill:#BB85AD;
    
}
.button2:active {
      -fx-text-fill:#BB85AD;
}
```

Error Massage :

```
Dec 31, 2021 5:42:23 PM javafx.css.CssParser term
WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-fx-background-color: linear-gradient : (to bottom left,#5f0a87, #a4508b);}: Unexpected token ':' at [1,40]
```

Is there anyone who can help me solve this problem?

Comment: Don’t set tags for versions of JavaFX you aren’t using.

Comment: I don’t think the error message matches the css you provided.  The error message is pretty explicit, you have an unnecessary `:`  character in the css at line 1 column 40.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.linear-grad {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #5f0a87, #a4508b);
}

.button1 {
    -fx-background-color: #5F0E81;
    -fx-text-fill       : #ffffff;
}

.button1:hover {
    -fx-text-fill: #6E1988;
}

.button1:pressed {
    -fx-text-fill: #CEB2D7;
}

.button1:active {
    -fx-text-fill: #B184BF;
}

.button2 {
    -fx-background-color: #863684;
    -fx-text-fill       : #ffffff;
}

.button2:hover {
    -fx-text-fill: #994984;
}

.button2:pressed {
    -fx-text-fill: #BB85AD;
}

.button2:active {
    -fx-text-fill: #BB85AD;
}
```